# Are these the same " In five of the six disciplines" and "in five out of the six diciplines"

Tags: grammar, phrases

As in the title mentioned above

Are these are the same?

> In five of the six disciplines

and

> In five out of the six disciplines

Are these of the same meaning? Otherwise, which phrase is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Both mean the same thing, and I don't believe there would be any reason to use one rather than the other.  One might say that the first version is a bit more "efficient" than the second, but that's about all.